# Synchronization of Google and Microsoft calendars

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, gmail

I would like to synchronize Microsoft and Google calendars across multiple devices, particularly Ubuntu-based. I have managed to merge the two calendars from Microsoft Outlook and Gmail on an Android device with the Outlook app. However, I have not been able to synchronize the two calendars on the Ubuntu-based systems. I have tried various combinations: The web-based Microsoft Outlook, calendar.google.com, Thunderbird's calendar and gnome-calender.

It seem not possible to get the Microsoft Outlook calendar into the Google system as far as I can determine.

For the other way, I have added a calendar (Danish "Tilføj kalender") in the web-based Microsoft owa interface. I can import an unzip .ics exported from Google, but changes in Google Calendar is not reflected in the Microsoft calendar. I have tried adding a person in the Google calendar setting with my Microsoft-based email address, but this does not seems to be accepted. I have tried to add the https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=... link from the Google Calendar setting to the add calendar in the web-based Microsoft system. But in vain. I am unsure if the URL format in the Microsoft settings field is correct.

The gnome-calendar has the synchronized Google calendar. I have tried to add an "Microsoft Exchange Account" for the Microsoft calendar but this does not show up.

My Thunderbird's calendar has the Microsoft calendar. I have added the "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=..." link to the "Location" field in the "Edit Calendar" setting, but the Google calendar does not show.

I wonder if I am missing a combination of settings or a plugin.

Comment: If I write an answer telling you how to get google calendar into thunderbird, would that answer your question? (I'm a bit confused by all the options in this question)

Comment: A web-based calendar would be best. But a setup in Thunderbird would also be ok.

Comment: In lieu of writing an answer then, I'll just refer you to the tbird directions for this. I use this and it works fine. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar

Comment: Following "Importing the calendar into Lightning", I do not see the "Choose Google Calendar" option af "On the network". I see ICalendar and CalDAV. When I try to install the "Provider for Google Calendar" I cannot install it because it is not verified.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? I have no issue with using the Provider. https://i.imgur.com/vGzAQDg.png

Comment: Version 91.0.2 does not verify on my system. It is the top one at  https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/versions/ 78.0.1 neither verifies.

Comment: I can't help but notice that you did not state what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: The current system I am sitting at is a Ubuntu derivation called Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS

Comment: Pop is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to install Provider for Google Calendar with Thunderbird -> Tools -> Add-ons with no problem now. From there I could import the calendar wth File -> New -> Calendar -> On the network. There might also have been a cookie problem for the sign-on in Google.Cookies are now enabled in Thunderbird: Edit -> Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Accept cookies from sites.

Comment: "Pop is off topic here." Pop is an Ubuntu derivation where the sources comes in from archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: If you wish to discuss the topicality of questions, please go to https://meta.askubuntu.com/